# UI Automation how to perform swipe to delete

Tags: ios7, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

have seen answers of how to swipe, but the swipe to delete doesnt seem to work with `dragInsideWithOptions()` or `dragFromToForDuration()`

any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me. I didn't realize until I read the docs that the coordinates are normalized to (0,1). I saw where some people were having trouble with iOS 7 - apparently the swipe distance needs to be longer than it had to be in the past.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var win = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();

win.tableViews()[0].cells()[0].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.75, y:0.5}, endOffset:{x:0.25, y:0.5}, duration:0.25});
win.tableViews()[0].cells()[0].buttons()["Delete"].tap();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was targeting iOS 7 when I wrote this. I don't have access to that code any longer, so I can't verify. Sorry about that.